# What is the advantage of static site generated pages (SSG) over non-SSG pages plus cache?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cdn, static-site

[Next.js](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#next-gen-static-site-generation-ssg-support) recently released version 9.3 which supports static site generation at build time. Essentially one of the new methods provided is `getStaticProps` which fetches data at build time.

My question is what is the advantage of using such workflow if I use a CDN, for example AWS Cloudfront? Even if the page is built dynamically per each request in (as in `getInitialProps` in older Next.js versions) the page will still get cached by Cloudfront and returned very fast. So I'm wondering what is the real-world use case of `getStaticProps` because any serious website already uses CDN. I understand that the technology is primarily geared towards CMS websites but even in those content may change periodically on the same resource (e.g. an article had a grammar mistake and it must be corrected) and it's an advantage that the page can change dynamically not per build time.

Comment: 10 months later, did you get a better understanding of the differences?

Comment: would love to know if someone has a better understanding on this

Answer (score 2):

We discuss this a lot in our production environment and are performing an upgrade to 9.4 to enable SSG created pages behind our CDN in a large enterprise scale site.''

**Here is our reasoning**

1. We offload about 98% of our traffic on regular days but even the 2%
   trickling into origin can cause havoc depending on the resource requested and traffic volume, sizing our origin becomes a nightmare because things get impacted seasonally. We see people mis-typing url's all the time including ad campaigns, email links etc.
2. CDN invalidation occurs daily in our use case, e.g: A common content component that is server side rendered may affect multiple pages but not the entire site, in this case pages which are not affected can just be served back by a origin that has static optimization.Depending on what the content is e.g: inline styles on a HTML page we may have to flush all HTML's on the CDN.

**TL;DR**

Statically generating pages means that the origin is smart to replay back pages without processing crucial resources. It's down to your scale and how much traffic you are playing with.

Comment: by the way for 404 pages you have this https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#automatic-static-optimization-for-404

Comment: they don't mis-type the same way - so yes, this works for Repeat 404's but new combinations cannot be optimized until they are hit once.

Comment: I guess this works with static routes but if you have dynamic ones how does this help you? If you use getStaticPaths with fallback true then the ui server will try to get the non-existing page